# Newsletter examples don't show

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter

I saw this on [Code Golf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com):

> [image: screenshot of ad]

So I thought, "Okay, I'll see an example!"

> *click image to enlarge*
> [image: screenshot of error]

Apparently, it doesn't show, and this is the error:

> Refused to display 'https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=codegolf.stackexchange.com&suppressPromotion=true' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

When I go to the link it works. It appears to be a cross-domain issue, with Code Golf.SE trying to access http://stackexchange.com.

Comment: Just the HTTP header...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have enabled framing for newsletters specifically, it's now live.  Thanks for the report!

Comment: And [it's back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329307/newsletter-preview-throwing-content-security-policy-error)..

Comment: Nick, the previews are [blocked for all Newsletters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gADQn.jpg). It seemed to work a couple of weeks ago but it's broken again.