# Example newsletter content for Stack Overflow is missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter, ssl

When I try to load the example newsletter from the right sidebar ad, the same observable behavior as described in [Newsletter examples don't show](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194562/newsletter-examples-dont-show) occurs.

The firebug console shows this error:

> Blocked loading mixed active content "https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=stackoverflow.com&suppressPromotion=true"

Comment: Aha, I think I know where the problem is then. Will look.

Answer (score 3):

Switched that link from HTTP to protocol-relative, so this will be fixed as of the next build. (2015.12.1.3939 on MSE/MSO, 2015.12.1.3045 elsewhere).

Comment: Confirmed, works! : )  [checked after the downtime]