# Newsletter preview throwing content security policy error

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, newsletter

When I click any preview link from [Stack Exchange Newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) page, it doesn't display any preview content.

Instead of that it throwing an error.

In **Mozilla FireFox** I'm receiving the following error:

[image]

In plain text:

> Blocked by Content Security Policy
>
> An error occurred during a connection to blender.stackexchange.com.
>
> Firefox prevented this page from loading in this way because the page has a content security policy that disallows it.

In **Google Chrome** I'm receiving the following error:

[image]

In plain text:

> Refused to display 'https://blender.stackexchange.com/newsletter/preview' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

Comment: Someone rolled back the fix Nick put [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194562/newsletter-examples-dont-show). :/

Comment: [Still broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gADQn.jpg) on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the community digest preview is working fine now. It has been solved recently.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: community digest preview]